# How can I get desired queries with these 3 tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 sql tables: In first I store products with key PID. In second I save invoices with key RID. Third table is used to describe how many of each product is bought in this invoice. I need a help with the two issues, and as someone who rarely worked with sql, this is somewhat hard.

1) What would be the query for the most bought products in the last 3 months.

2) What would be the query to increase the price of these 3 products by 5%?

DB:

```
CREATE TABLE Products(
    pid INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    price DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    stock INTEGER NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Invoices(
    rid INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    invoicedate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Orders(
    rid INTEGER,
    pid INTEGER,
    quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES Products(pid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (rid) REFERENCES Invoices(rid) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for increasing price

```
    update product set price=price*. 05 where pid in( give your pid seperated by comma)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first query you didn't specified how many products you want to get, so here is a query to retrieve all of the products that has been bought, ordered by the most quantity to less:

```
SELECT P.name, P.type, SUM(O.quantity) Quant
FROM Orders AS O
INNER JOIN Products AS P
ON O.pid = P.pid
GROUP BY P.name, P.type
ORDER BY Quant DESC
```

For the `UPDATE`, this is a way to do it with SQL Server:

```
UPDATE Products
SET price = price * 1.05
WHERE pid IN (  SELECT DISTINCT P.pid 
                FROM Orders AS O
                INNER JOIN Products AS P
                ON O.pid = P.pid
                GROUP BY P.pid
                ORDER BY SUM(O.Quantity) DESC)
```